# How to process 3D Images using Hadoop MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, image-processing, mapreduce, d3dimage

I am working on a project where I need to process around 10,000 3D Images. So can you suggest me how can I do this using HADOOP MapReduce so that I can achieve parallelism and get the result as quick as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this at my end and if I face any problems, then I will post them here.

Answer (score 2):

while working with images you can use [HIPI(Hadoop Image Processing Interface)](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/).

Also some [tools and example](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/examples.html) programs from HIPI.

You can get started with [this](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/gettingstarted.html).

And yes it is entirely up to you how you want to process your images.

I believe stereoscopy or 3D imaging stereoscopic imaging is a technique used to record and display 3D (three dimensional) images or an illusion of depth in an image. Stereoscopic images provide spatial information that trick a user's brain into believing and seeing depth in the images.

So their must be sets of images you can process.